# how to check if the same image is displayed in more than one picturebox

Tags: c#

I am loading images into 5 pictureBoxs and want the program to make sure that no images are the same in any of the pictureboxs.

```
if ((pictureBox2 == pictureBox1) || (pictureBox3 == pictureBox1) ||
    (pictureBox4 == pictureBox1) || (pictureBox5 == pictureBox1) ||
    (pictureBox3 == pictureBox2) || (pictureBox4 == pictureBox2) ||
    (pictureBox5 == pictureBox2) || (pictureBox4 == pictureBox3) ||
    (pictureBox5 == pictureBox3) || (pictureBox5 == pictureBox4))
    {
```

This  does not work and seems very clunky.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: As far as I know your code should not be working, picturebox1 will never be equals to picturebox2 because they are 2 diferent instances

Comment: I have gone through it a few times and it dose not work. How can I check if one picture box holds the same image as another?

Comment: Please edit your question, and make the subject something relevant to the question being asked. The current title is meaningless, and it will have absolutely no value to future readers who find it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like bto.rdz indicated, you can't compare two `PictureBox` controls like that. They're all separate instances and won't ever be equal.

You might be able to compare the `Image` property on them to see if two or more have been set to the same image. I'm not positive this will work in your case, but it's something you can try.

First, create a collection of PictureBoxes you want to check...

```
var pictureBoxes =
    new[] {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5};
```

... then use LINQ to check for duplicates. Here I'm grouping by `Image`, then using `Count()` to see if any two (or more) `PictureBox` controls refer to the same image.

```
var hasDuplicates = pictureBoxes.GroupBy(x => x.Image).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```